# BJT short circuit failure cause in switch application

Tags: transistors, bjt, short-circuit

i read in this [discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63568/what-can-cause-a-drain-source-short-in-a-fet) about the FET short circuit causes.    But I want to know what leads to BJT short-circuit ?

Comment: In any specific context or use-case,? For example, in a power amplifier circuit, or inside an analogue component, like an operational amplifier?  Or is this just curiosity?

Comment: It's just curiosity , i know that FET are more adapted for high power switch applications and can fail in EOS conditions or in case of breakdown voltage of at the drain, but what about the BJT ?

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Often it helps the community give good answers by asking reasonably complete and specific questions. So I was just trying to understand.

Comment: Do you have the answer ?

Comment: I apologise, my answer would be thermal or electrical breakdown too. I tend to use big-fat-MOSFETs, or ICs, and low-voltages :-( I was just trying to encourage you to add enough detail to help you get a good answer.

Comment: why the down votes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual reasons: thermal or electric breakdown.